# How do I get image data from local JSON file data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a JSON file in public folder and image in src/assets/img/
If I had to do it with reactjs, I can just do:

```
import flat from "../../../assets/img/two.jpg";
```

And in JSON file, I gave the exact location of the image file but it cannot locate image

```
"apartment_image":"../../../assets/img/two.jpg"
```

Now it cannot find the image file.
My code looks like this :

```
<div className="img-section">
        <img className="flat-image" src={data.apartment_image} alt="" />
      </div>
```

Everything loads except the image.

Comment: Hey Saran, have you tried to `console.log(data.apartment_image)` ? what does it return ?

Comment: It returns "../../../assets/img/two.jpg" and when I use this location like this:
`import flat from "../../../assets/img/two.jpg";` 
in the top of reactjs, it works but when using the data from api, I can't

Comment: have you tried to use `absolute` path instead of `relative` path ? look this [example](https://www.jquery-az.com/html-img-src-image-source-attribute-with-path-possibilities-5-examples/)

Comment: Thank you very much sir! The absolute path worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should give absolute path to get the image...
Like this : " http://localhost:3000/flat-trade/img/two.jpg "